# Twitter API Only Showing Two

Tags: javascript, twitter, conditional-statements

I am using Jason Mayes Twitter JS on a website of mine and everything works until I use php conditional statements.

I have included Jason's javascript in my page which looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/4utuY/1/

The fiddle works and when I add it to my site everything works until I use a php conditional which causes the third tweet to disappear. The code looks like:

```
    <?php if (is_page("Youth")) { ?>
        <p><strong>Follow us: <a href="https://twitter.com/brandork">@brandork</a></strong></p>
        <div id="tweets"></div>
        <hr />
    <?php } ?>
    <p><strong>Follow us: <a href="https://twitter.com/epopengate">@epopengate</a></strong></p>
    <div id="talk"></div>
    <?php if (!is_page("Youth")) { ?>
        <hr />
        <p><strong>Follow us: <a href="https://twitter.com/nazcompassion">@nazcompassion</a></strong></p>
        <div id="tweets2"></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

I created another function called twitterFetcher.fetch2 for the third one and the conditional works, but why did I have to do that? Is there some kind of limit the JS has preventing more than two to display? If I remove the conditional code the three display just fine...any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears the problem with your code is that your PHP code changes the HTML output meaning some elements are removed.

Because of this, the 3 lines of JavaScript at the end of the JavaScript file used to call the component, are expecting these DOM elements to be there all the time.

You need to also make these conditional. For example if you had jQuery on your site you could use:

```
if ($('#tweets').length > 1 ) {
  twitterFetcher.fetch('347356802423345152', 'tweets', 1, true);
}
```

Same for the other two of course. This way the JavaScript is only executed if the DOM element exists, so an error is not thrown for trying to access something that does not exist yet!

Answer (score 0):

I have the Javascript as an external file - I ended up removing the following lines from my JS file:

```
twitterFetcher.fetch('347355465329565696', 'talk', 1, true, true, false);
twitterFetcher.fetch('347356802423345152', 'tweets', 1, true, true, false);
twitterFetcher.fetch('347364680194465794', 'tweets2', 1, true, true, false);
```

I replaced those lines with the following in my head, head - right below the link to my JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if ($('#tweets').length > 0) {
                twitterFetcher.fetch('347356802423345152', 'tweets', 1, true, true, false);
            }
            if ($('#talk').length > 0) {
                twitterFetcher.fetch('347355465329565696', 'talk', 1, true, true, false);
            }
            if ($('#tweets2').length > 0) {
                twitterFetcher.fetch('347364680194465794', 'tweets2', 1, true, true, false); 
            }
        });
    </script>
```

That's it, now everything works as expected, with one function instead of two and I know why!!

Thanks Jason!! I appreciate all the back and forths until we got working!

Thanks,
Josh